# What is the simplest way to add outlet to my view controller?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa, ipad

When I add new view, I always do same and boring work.

If I add UIWebView, I would do follows,

- add codes to header file. ( declare, property )
- add codes to source file. ( synthesize, viewDidUnload, dealloc )
- add UIWebView in IB and connect to the outlet in File's Owner.

[ViewController.h]

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    UIWebView *_webView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;

@end
```

[ViewController.m]

```
@synthesize webView = _webView;

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    self.webView = nil;
}
- (void)dealloc
{
    [_webView release];
    [super dealloc];    
}
```

What if I should add 3 labels and 2 buttons?
What if I have to add textview and some imageviews?

Don't you think it is boring? I would like to listen to your idea.

I hope there will be more easy and simple way to add outlet to the code.
Does anybody have a good idea? :)

Comment: Use storyboard. It will do step 1 and 2 for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using `Interface Builder`, If you select an Object drag it's reference to your header, you'll see a popup where you can name it so theres less typing for you to do. As seen below:

[image]

This will automatically declare the `IBOutlet UIButton *myButton` for you, and insert the `release` and `nil` code into `dealloc` and `viewDidUnload` methods.

Same method also works for actions, as seen below.

[image]

Once you `Connect` it will automatically insert the new Action `-(IBAction)cancelSelected:(id)sender` into your `@implementation` class.

Point being, all that's boring for you to do can be done in `2` Reference connections, and inputting data into `2` fields. :)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode 4, you can simply control drag from a UI element to the .h/.m file. If you drag to the .h, Xcode will create a property for you and synthesize that in the corresponding .m, if you drag to the .m, Xcode will stub out an IBAction method for you.

Also, I would recommend switching to ARC, to avoid having to worry about memory management.

Answer (score 1):

If you are having xcode 4.0 you can create outlet property by drag and drop.
Follow the steps:

1. open the xcode
2. open you nib file where you need to create an outlet.
3. Click on the middle tab of the Editor which at right up corner. It will open a new file adjacent to your nib.
4. Make sure it is the .h file of the controller where you want to create the outlet.
5. Now select the control, right click on it and drag to the .h file. Name the outlet. Thats it. It will create you a property and it will synthesize it automatically.
6. It will also insert the code for `dealloc` and `viewDidUnload`.

Hope this help.